# Background python thread that sends serialport data to React

Tags: python, reactjs, multithreading, flask, background-process

I am writing a React app with a Flask backend that I want to be able to receive data through a serial port, process this data, and graph it. Currently I am using the backend to send certain pieces of data (current time and available ports) to React. I want to set up a background Python thread that will run continuously to read data from the serial port using pyserial, process it, and send it to React, but I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this is. My initial search brought me to [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html); however, I'm not sure if it's a good option for a continuous task. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that reading from a serial port is normally done in a blocking way. That means you do not poll periodically, but instead you open the port once and then read all the time, waiting for new data to come.

What you need is a separate [thread](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). This is a part of the program that runs in parallel to your normal web server. Then you need some sort of data base to communicate between that thread and the web server. If you want your data to be persistent between device and server restarts, you should install a real database like Postgres. If not, you can simply use an array in your application memory.

In the thread, read from the serial port and write the values to the database/array.

In your REST endpoint, you output the last X values.

Then your client can poll against this endpoint.

(If you want to do it really fancy, you can use a more event-driven approach, but this would be more complicated to implement)